# Test whether multiple HTML dropdowns are equal but not null with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I dont know how to do this following in a simple way. Help would be very appreciated.

I have 10 select inputs on a HTML form

```
<select id="PurchaseType1" name="PurchaseType1">
<select id="PurchaseType2" name="PurchaseType2">
...
<select id="PurchaseType10" name="PurchaseType10">
```

When I submit the form, I would like to run a function to check all the values of these select inputs and update a variable.

I want to set this variable to the value of the select if all the values are equal (eliminating those that were not filled in - blank or null).

If there are differences (not including the null or emptys) I would set the variable to a text value of "Multiple".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery, the following will get you close on form submit; when complete, areEqual will tell you whether or not all the values are equal.  Substitute "Select One" with whatever the default value of the select list is.  Some developers use -1.

```
var values = [
   $("#PurchaseType1").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType2").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType3").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType4").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType5").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType6").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType7").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType8").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType9").val(),
   $("#PurchaseType10").val() ];

var initialValue = null;
var areEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length && areEqual; i++) {
      if (initialValue == null) {
          initialValue = values[i];
      }

      if (values[i] != initialValue ||
         values[i] == "Select One") {
              areEqual = false;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can one use `reduce` to compare a collection of `select` elements? With a common class added to each `select` element:

```
<select class="PurchaseTypes" id="PurchaseType1" name="PurchaseType1">
```

...and some JS wrangling:

```
function compare () {
    var pT = document.getElementsByClassName("PurchaseTypes")
    var comp = Array.prototype.reduce.call(pT, function(a, b) {
        if (!b.selectedIndex) { return a }
        else if ('Multiple' !== a && (a.selectedIndex === b.selectedIndex || !a.selectedIndex)) { return b }
        else { return 'Multiple' }
    })
    comp = (comp.selectedIndex || 0 === comp.selectedIndex)? comp.selectedIndex: comp
    document.getElementById('comp').innerHTML = comp
}
```

...one gets either the selected index, if all are the same or not selected, or the flag "Multiple" if two or more are selected and they're different.

Toy with this code here: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/sbff3s70/

Am I missing something?